# how to add param string after website url in wordpress?

Tags: urls

My website url is [www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com) and i want my website url to be as [www.abc.com/?2023-04-29](http://www.abc.com/?2023-04-29).
My website is build on wordpress.

So how do I add query strings after site url?

Comment: this is almost certainly going to require some form of redirect, but what's the reason for adding this? Everything after the `?` is not strictly a part of the URL but the query parameters, so even `www.abc.com/?2023-04-29` has the URL `www.abc.com`, and posts such as `/test` would not be located at `www.abc.com/?2023-04-29/test` they would be at `www.abc.com/test` or at best `www.abc.com/test/?2023-04-29`

Comment: Is there any plugin of script code which help me to redirect and add parameters?

Comment: recommendations are offtopic here, can you add some context for what you're trying to do that requires this?

Comment: For example My website is abc.com and when some one open my website the url of website open as www.abc.com but i want that the url of my website open as www.abc.com/?year-month-date.

Comment: that's clear from your question, I was asking why you wanted that though, is this an attempt to invalidate cache? Is it just for the homepage or is it all pages?

Comment: For all the pages.